# C++ P2P Listen on a port without port forwarding

Tags: c++, p2p, router

I'm trying to write a C++ chat program that is based on Peer To Peer technique, with no need to a server. Say peers connect to each other using their IP addresses as identifier.

Can I listen to incoming connections without configuring port forwarding on the router?

Comment: Do you know the difference between a "publicly routable" IP address and a "private" IP?

Comment: Yes I do. In fact, I want to just open a port automatically when I launch the program, because I don't want to configure port forwarding for every port I will listen on. I just want it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if peers are not behind a NAT. If they are you have to make port mapping(forward ports). You can easily write a function to check if a peers machine is behind NAT or not. And if it is, you can reconsider using server as a transfer place of the messages between peers.

Edit:
You can also think about using public VPN as a proxy(with port forward included). However, it is hard to find free one. Even if you are willing to pay for it, you have no assurance that no one will listen to it and you will be dependent of the uptime of the VPN servers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I make port mapping through UPnP?

Comment: @Kira: people could answer your question better is you clarify which situation you are designing for: publicly routable IP at both ends, both ends on same subnet, or NAT separating them. Yes thew are ways to automatically punch through NAT, both with and without uPNP... none work on all routers.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, both peers are behind NAT, how can I forward ports automatically?